# floor ceiling proof

Tags: inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Hi I would like to proof without using induction that:
$$
 \left\lceil\frac{n}{m}\right\rceil  \leq \frac{n+m-1}{m} 
$$

I tried:

$$
 \left\lceil\frac{n}{m}\right\rceil  \leq \frac{n}{m}+\frac{m}{m}-\frac{1}{m}
$$

But dont see any pattern.

does any one have hints?

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $n=km+r, 0 \le r \lt m$ using the usual division with remainder.

Comment: ok I tried that and get $$k+\frac{r}{m}+1-\frac{1}{m}$$. Should I see a pattern?

Comment: Now note that $\lceil \frac nm \rceil = k$ if $r=0$ and $k+1$ if $r \gt 0$

Comment: Based on Ross Millikan's comment...write $ k = \left( \frac{n}{m} - \frac{r}{m} \right) $

Answer (score 2):

$$\left\lceil\frac{n}{m}\right\rceil < \frac{n}{m} + 1$$
$$m\left\lceil\frac{n}{m}\right\rceil < n + m$$
$$m\left\lceil\frac{n}{m}\right\rceil \leq n + m - 1$$
$$\left\lceil\frac{n}{m}\right\rceil \leq \frac{n + m - 1}{m}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\left\lceil\frac n m\right\rceil<\frac nm+1=\frac{n+m}m.$$
The inequality is sharp and the smallest difference can be $\frac1m$ because only fractions with denominator $m$ can be on the right side. Therefore
$$\left\lceil\frac n m\right\rceil\le\frac{n+m}m-\frac1m=\frac{n+m-1}m.$$